# Vue Reactivity vs Angular RxJS: how to handle Async UI updates that depends on timers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rxjs, reactive-programming

How would you display a loading spinner, following an HTTP request (or any other async operation that happens over a period of time), based on the following logic?

- wait X time (=100ms) and display nothing
- if after X time (=100ms) the data arrived, display the data immediately.
- if after X time (=100ms) the data has not arrived, display the spinner for at least Y time (=250ms), and until the data arrives.

In Angular/RxJS you would do something like this in your Service:

```
/**
     * We want to display the loading indicator only if the requests takes more than `${INITIAL_WAITING_TIME}
     * if it does, we want to wait at least `${MINIMUM_TIME_TO_DISPLAY_LOADER} before emitting
     */
    const startLoading$ = of({}).pipe(
      tap(() => this.setState({ loading: true })),
      delay(MINIMUM_TIME_TO_DISPLAY_LOADER),
      switchMap(() => EMPTY)
    );

    const hideLoading$ = of(null).pipe(
      tap(() => this.setState({ loading: false }))
    );

    const timer$ = timer(INITIAL_WAITING_TIME).pipe();

    /**
     * We want to race two streams:
     *
     * - initial waiting time: the time we want to hold on any UI updates
     * to wait for the API to get back to us
     *
     * - data: the response from the API.
     *
     * Scenario A: API comes back before the initial waiting time
     *
     * We avoid displaying the loading spinner altogether, and instead we directly update
     * the state with the new data.
     *
     * Scenario B: API doesn't come back before initial waiting time.
     *
     * We want to display the loading spinner, and to avoid awkward flash (for example the response comes back 10ms after the initial waiting time) we extend the delay to 250ms
     * to give the user the time to understand the actions happening on the screen.
     */
    const race$ = race(timer$, data$).pipe(
      switchMap((winner) =>
        typeof winner === 'number' ? startLoading$ : EMPTY
      )
    );

    return concat(race$, hideLoading$, data$).pipe(filter(Boolean));
```

In Vue, I could not find a better way than using `setTimeout` and nesting `watch` to react to changes to a reactive property:

[Link to Vue Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const displayUI = ref<boolean>(false);
const loading = ref<boolean>(false);
const data = ref<string | null>(null);
  
setTimeout(() => {
  // after 100ms we want to display a UI to the user
  displayUI.value = true;
  
  // if data has arrived, we can display and exit this logic
  if (data.value) {
    return;
  }

  // if it has not arrived
  // we show spinner for at least 250ms
  loading.value = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    // at this point, we should display data, but only after data has arrived
   // Question is: without RxJS, how can we 
   if (data.value) {
     loading.value = false;
   } else {
     // can we nest a watcher?
     watch(data, (value) => {
     if (value) {
       loading.value = false
       data.value = 'it worked!'
     }
   })
   }
  }, 2500)
    
    
}, 1000) 

// fake timer, let's say our API request takes X amount of time to come back
setTimeout(() => {
  data.value = 'Data arrived'
}, 4000)
  

</script>

<template>
  <template v-if="displayUI">
    <h1 v-if="!data && !loading">
    No Data
  </h1>
  <h1 v-if="!loading && data">
    {{ data }}
  </h1>
  <h1 v-if="loading">
    Loading...
    </h1>
  </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Etus Flask for his answer that set me up in the right direction. Having used Observable for this type of logic, I never actually used `Promise.race` and completely forgot about its existance.

[I created an example that can hopefully also help others (Vue Playground)](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) and contains the feature fully implemented.

I added some time logs so you can see the timeline of the different steps.

```
<script setup>
  
import { ref, onMounted, reactive } from 'vue';
  
const loading = ref(false)
const data = ref(null); 
  

onMounted(async () => {
  const p = getData();
  const res = await Promise.race([delay(100), p])
  
  if (!res) {
    loading.value = true;

    await delay(250);
    const d = await p;

    // assign data for UI to display
    loading.value = false;
    data.value = d;
  } else {
    data.value = res;
  }
})

async function delay(time){
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(res, time)
  })
}
  
 // we simulate a network request
 async function getData() {
   return new Promise(res => {
     setTimeout(res, 200, {data: true})
   });
  }
  
</script>

<template>
  <h1 v-if="loading">
    Loading...
  </h1>
   <h1 v-if="!loading && data">
    Data
  </h1>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Observables are heavily used in Angular, both in the ecosystem and framework itself. When there's no good use case for them, it's beneficial to stick to promises for asynchronous code.

Asynchronous side effects go to lifecycle hooks instead of setup body:

```
onMounted(async () => {
  const dataPromise = getData();

  let  result = await Promise.race([delay(100), dataPromise])

  if (!result) {
    loading.value = true;

    // not awaited
    Promise.all([delay(250), dataPromise]
      .finally(() => loading.value = false);

    result = await dataPromise;
  }

  data.value = result;
});
```

The loader itself is easily implemented with Vue suspense feature, this requires to split the component into 2, the parent hosts  tag, and the child does asynchronous work with `script setup` and `await`

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot about the existence of `Promise.race`, which was the missing piece in the puzzle :)